# Is there a way to update certain objects 'live' on a webpage with Python 3?

Tags: python, http, handler

I'm busy with my own http handler and I have managed to make a neat website with my own-written database handler.

However, is it someway possible to update a certain object live on a webpage? For example:

```
<h1>Hello</h1>
```

To:

```
<h1>Bye</h1>
```

LIVE? Because writing something to the webpage uses

```
self.wfile.write('<h1>Hello</h1>')
```

Is there something for example self.wfile.change (doesn't exist) that can change a certain object written to a user?

I know how to update data non-live(so by refreshing the webpage), but I really want the user to stay on a certain webpage and still get data updated...

... without javascript or php but **Python 3**

Comment: Browsers generally execute javascript -- not python.  Of course, you could write some JS to fetch new data from the python running on your server and then display it on the page using JS ... But there's no way to get around needing a client side language (i.e. not python).

Comment: I think you can use`socket`. But still you have to use `javascript`. But backend can be JS or Python or etc.

Comment: Do you have a link of an example or tutorial or documentation latheef itzmeontv? Thanks for the help btw.

Comment: You need to use a client-side language, that is to say, Javascript, to initiate any such change. You can handle AJAX requests from Python, if you want, and the Javascript can be made very simple. But you do need some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you can do in PHP you can do in Python 3, so long as your web server supports Python apps.

There are two ways to change a portion of a page. One way is to rewrite the DOM using JavaScript. That's fine unless you already have a lot of viewers who have turned off JavaScript in their browsers. The other way is to divide the page into boxes, each containing a separate HTML document with a separate URL, and reference each box with an `<iframe seamless>` element in the main page. Then you can have each `<iframe>` refresh itself periodically.

`seamless.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>SO Example</title><style type="text/css">
iframe[seamless] { display: block; width: 100%; border: 0 }
</style></head><body>
<iframe seamless src="headerbar.html" style="height: 3rem"></iframe>
no main refresh 
<iframe seamless src="body.html" style="height: 20rem"></iframe>
</body></html>
```

`headerbar.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5"> <!-- change this to how often to pull the changes -->
<style type="text/css">
html, body { overflow: hidden } /* this avoids a scrollbar in parent page's box */
h1 { margin: 0; font-size: 200% } /* explicit font-size to fit height of parent page's box */
</style></head><body>
<h1>Inner refresh!</h1>
</body></html>
```

`body.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>
Lorem ipsum
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't. The fact is that the data was already sent to the client, and there is no way to perform such a replacement server-side. You need to instruct the client to perform said update, and Javascript is your only realistic option here.

If you want to stick with Python, you can explore projects like [Brython](http://www.brython.info/), which allows you to execute a subset of Python client-side, but keep in mind that most online learning and help resources are focused on Javascript.